# Summarize unique column in row

Tags: sql, pivot-table, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm new to Firebird and need your help.

I have a stored procedure with following reduced output:

| Player | Team | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Reus | Ahlen | 18 |
| Lewandowski | Posen | 19 |
| Reus | MG | 11 |
| Reus | BVB | 11 |
| Lewandowski | BVB | 9 |
| Haaland | BVB | 9 |

I want to summarize the Players and transform Team&Number to a new column.

The output should be:

| Player | Station 1 | Station 2 | Station 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Reus | Ahlen 18 | MG 11 | BVB 11 |
| Lewandowski | Posen 19 | BVB 9 |  |
| Haaland | BVB 9 |  |  |

I am using Firebird 2.5.8

Comment: How do you determine which team+number should end up in which station column?

Comment: It would be nice, if the first station has the highest number. 2nd Station 2nd highest Number... But it is not necessary that it is sortet with numbers. for example if REUS can has station1 = MG 11 / Station2 = Ahlen 18 / Station3 = BVB 11 its also ok

Comment: There are some tricks to do this, but it is easier to do in Firebird 3.0 than in Firebird 2.5. Would you mind a stored procedure based solution, or does it need to be a 'normal'  SQL query?

Comment: Yeah i heard it, thats are some tricks available in Firebird 3.0. But i cant upgrade it... A 'normal' SQL query would be nice, because i got the output from a stored procedure. But if can do two stored procedure in one, it would be also ok. Thx

Comment: Search for "[firebird] pivot" and you would have a plenty of results. All in all, varying columns data is not a job for regular "maths" like RDBMS/SQL, it is a job for "reporting tools" class of application. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896351 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698515 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449169 or any other similar question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the remainder of this answer, I'm using the following setup:

```sql
create table player (
  player varchar(100) not null,
  team varchar(100) not null,
  number smallint not null
);

commit;

insert into player (player, team, number) values ('Reus', 'Ahlen', 18);
insert into player (player, team, number) values ('Lewandowski', 'Posen', 19);
insert into player (player, team, number) values ('Reus', 'MG', 11);
insert into player (player, team, number) values ('Reus', 'BVB', 11);
insert into player (player, team, number) values ('Lewandowski', 'BVB', 9);
insert into player (player, team, number) values ('Haaland', 'BVB', 9);

commit;
```

The examples assume that the player name is sufficient to uniquely identify the player.

Because of the nature of Firebird's DSQL dialect and implementation of query execution, the number of 'station' columns is fixed. In this example, I'm using three, like your question, but this can be extended to more columns if necessary. In Firebird 2.5, generating the desired pivot table is messy, and will likely not perform well.

A basic, pure SQL solution, would be something like:

```sql
with unique_players as (
  select distinct player from player
)
select 
  player,
  (select team || ' ' || number 
   from player 
   where player = unique_players.player 
   order by number desc
   rows 1) as station_1,
  (select team || ' ' || number 
   from player 
   where player = unique_players.player 
   order by number desc
   rows 2 to 2) as station_2,
  (select team || ' ' || number 
   from player 
   where player = unique_players.player 
   order by number desc
   rows 3 to 3) as station_3
from unique_players;
```

In this example, we determine the unique players, and then select the first, second and third station using a subquery using [`rows`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-rows) (you can also use [`first`/`skip`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-first-skip), or, in Firebird 3.0 and higher, [`offset`/`fetch`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch))

An alternative, which likely performs better, is using a stored procedure or execute block, but the code does get more complex.

```sql
execute block 
  returns (
    player type of column player.player, 
    station_1 varchar(120), 
    station_2 varchar(120), 
    station_3 varchar(120)
  )
as
  declare station smallint = 0;
  declare current_player type of column player.player;
  declare current_team type of column player.team;
  declare current_number type of column player.number;
begin
  for select player, team, number 
      from player 
      order by player, number desc
      into current_player, current_team, current_number
  do
  begin
      if (current_player is distinct from player) then
      begin
         -- output row when player changes
         if (player is not null) then suspend;
         station = 1;
         player = current_player;
         station_1 = current_team || ' ' || current_number;
      end
      else
      begin
        station = station + 1;
        if (station = 2) then
        begin
          station_2 = current_team || ' ' || current_number;
        end
        else if (station = 3) then
        begin
          station_3 = current_team || ' ' || current_number;
        end
        -- rows for station > 3 are ignored
      end
  end
  -- output final player
  if (player is not null) then suspend;
end
```

This iterates over the rows, populating the output columns of the execute block, outputting them when the next player is found.

On the other hand, in Firebird 4.0, you could do something like:

Using [NTH_VALUE](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-windowfuncs-nth-value) window function:

```sql
select player, station_1, station_2, station_3
from (
  select 
    player, 
    row_number() over player_order as rownum,
    nth_value(team || number, 1) over player_order as station_1,
    nth_value(team || number, 2) over player_order as station_2,
    nth_value(team || number, 3) over player_order as station_3
  from player
  window player_order as (
    partition by player 
    order by number desc 
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
)
where rownum = 1
```

Or using [filtered aggregate functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-aggfuncs-filter):

```
with player_stations as (
  select 
    player, 
    team || ' ' || number as station, 
    row_number() over (partition by player order by number desc) as rownum
  from player
)
select 
  player, 
  max(station) filter (where rownum = 1) as station_1,
  max(station) filter (where rownum = 2) as station_2,
  max(station) filter (where rownum = 3) as station_3
from player_stations
group by player
```

Using a [lateral join](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-select-joins-lateral):

```sql
with player_stations as (
  select player, number, team || ' ' || number as station from player
)
select 
  player, 
  st1.station as station_1, 
  st2.station as station_2, 
  st3.station as station_3
from (select distinct player from player) p
left join lateral (
  select station
  from player_stations
  where player = p.player
  order by number desc
  fetch first row only
) st1 on true
left join lateral (
  select station
  from player_stations
  where player = p.player
  order by number desc
  offset 1 row
  fetch next row only
) st2 on true
left join lateral (
  select station
  from player_stations
  where player = p.player
  order by number desc
  offset 2 rows
  fetch next row only
) st3 on true
```

This is is similar to the first example, but pushing down the selection of the stations into the lateral join (a feature introduced in Firebird 4.0).

Comment: Perfect, Thanks it works. I use the soultion with "stored procedure or execute block"